# Which webserver i can use for ruby on rails application to carry heavy data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Which webserver i can use for ruby on rails application to carry heavy data
Which sever i can use rather than webric i want to carry heavy data webric is not properly supported  for this. Plz give me proper direction

Answer (score 3):

You have many alternatives. A good idea is to choose an application server and put it (or many) behind a web server or 'reverse proxy':

Web servers:

- [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)
- [NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/)

Both of these will handle a lot of traffic well. I'd suggest starting with Apache.

Behind your web server you then need one or many application servers:

- [Unicorn](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn)
- [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/)
- [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)

If I were you I'd start with Passenger and see how you get on.

On top of that, consider putting [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of your application for a significant requests/second increase for repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using Apache, Google has a mod that optimizes your configuration and can significantly improve your performance http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Rails, Apache + [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) (as mentioned above) is the most 'straightforward' way to go.

Having a good caching strategy is probably the best way to increase requests/second — before looking at Varnish though, I'd make sure you're handling your fragment caching properly and with enough granularity. See the [Rails Guide on caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) for more on this.